# Maven dependencies not accessible in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project managed by Maven which I am trying to get to work in Eclipse.
The problem is that all the dependencies which are being managed by Maven are not accessible inside the Java code.

In Eclipse I get an error on the imports for the respective classes:

```
The type org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair is not accessible
```

while when I try to build the project with Maven I get the error:

```
package org.apache.commons.math3.util is not visible (package org.apache.commons.math3.util is declared in the unnamed module, but module org.apache.commons.math3.util does not read it)
```

The dependencies have been downloaded by Maven and I can find them in the .m2 folder. I can even see the jar files when looking at the Java build path in Eclipse.

I also get the same error when I try to use Maven through the command line.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Try doing a mvn eclipse:eclipse command. And also clean & refresh your project in eclipse.

Comment: Clean the project and then right click on the project go to Maven -> Update project. I this should help.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? Also have you tried deleting your entire maven repository?

Comment: @AndreasHartmann I did try deleting the whole repository which didn't help. Here is the pom.xml: https://github.com/NetCal/DNC/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I suppose you have `module-info.java` in your project?

Comment: If it doesn't build on Maven command line or in Eclipse, there's likely a classpath issue of some sort. The error suggests the code is trying to access something that is not public. Try `mvn dependency:tree` (or the Eclipse equivalent). Look carefully at all usage of the commons Math library, to ensure versions are consistent. If not, that's where to start fixing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I don't know why but by not creating the module-info.java file when eclipse asked me, everything worked just fine.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer, please?  Should I have, or should I avoid `module-info.java` ?  If I need it, where does it go, and what does it contain?

Answer (score 2):

I had an incomplete module-info.java file : removing this fixed my problems.   I imagine setting this properly would also have worked but I need to understand module files.

Answer (score 0):

one time it happened to me too. Looks like a permission issue in my case or a disk space problem.
Also, try to delete the dependency from te disk and run `mvn clean install` again.
Make sure you're using an up-to-date maven version and perform ALT+F5 + force maven dependency update.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem and it is definitely not a disk space problem.

Comment: Are you able to share the code or portion of it so that I can test?

Comment: Also try to add the related jar to the build path as first attempt.
Also, check your .classpath file. Mine contains something like this and not all the dependencies:
`
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>
`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here didn't fix this for me. Instead it was a classpath clash, due to an "uberjar".

In the classpath were both:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.procedure</groupId>
    <artifactId>apoc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.11</version>
    <classifier>core</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The latter one is an uberjar, which also contains all the same classes from the former. Somehow Eclipse can't cope with this.

[image: Open Type]

The fix was to re-compile `apoc` without this dependency in the uberjar.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I created a new project with all same classes but my new project was not accessing any maven libraries.

In Visual Studio code when you create a new javaFX project, it generates [These files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfhI9.png) in which `module-info.java` contains [these values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXwMl.png). My project doesn't include fxml file so I was adding dependencies to [pom.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5X7f.png) .

So comparing it to the old project I deleted `module-info.java` file and all my *The package xyz is not accessible* errors are gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).